# Not able to connect to postgres using jdbc in pyspark shell

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am using standalone cluster on my local windows and trying to load data from one of our server using following code -

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.load(source="jdbc", url="jdbc:postgresql://host/dbname", dbtable="schema.tablename")
```

I have set the SPARK_CLASSPATH as -

```
os.environ['SPARK_CLASSPATH'] = "C:\Users\ACERNEW3\Desktop\Spark\spark-1.3.0-bin-hadoop2.4\postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc3.jar"
```

While executing sqlContext.load, it throws error mentioning "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql". I have tried searching web, but not able to find solution.

Comment: Its "No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql" only.. updated question.

Comment: Well in that case the required jar file with the driver is not available.

Comment: required jar file is present, but somehow SPARK is not able to recognize it.
There is some issue regarding SPARK_CLASSPATH. I am not sure on how to set the SPARK_CLASSPATH.

Comment: _"..\postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc3"_ doesn't sound like the name of a jar file as they usually end in `.jar`. You need to add the jar file to the classpath, not the folder containing the jar file.

Comment: added that Mark but still not working...

Comment: how are you running your script?

Comment: I am not running any script, I am simply using pyspark shell. 
Please refer to the detailed question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821518/apache-spark-jdbc-connection-not-working

Answer (score 5):

May be it will be helpful.

In my environment SPARK_CLASSPATH contains path to postgresql connector

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader, SQLContext
import os

sparkClassPath = os.getenv('SPARK_CLASSPATH', '/path/to/connector/postgresql-42.1.4.jar')

# Populate configuration
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setAppName('application')
conf.set('spark.jars', 'file:%s' % sparkClassPath)
conf.set('spark.executor.extraClassPath', sparkClassPath)
conf.set('spark.driver.extraClassPath', sparkClassPath)
# Uncomment line below and modify ip address if you need to use cluster on different IP address
#conf.set('spark.master', 'spark://127.0.0.1:7077')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

url = 'postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgresql'
properties = {'user':'username', 'password':'password'}

df = DataFrameReader(sqlContext).jdbc(url='jdbc:%s' % url, table='tablename', properties=properties)

df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

This piece of code allows to use pyspark where you need. For example, I've used it in Django project.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with mysql, and was never able to get it to work with the SPARK_CLASSPATH approach.  However I did get it to work with extra command line arguments, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821518/apache-spark-jdbc-connection-not-working/30947090#30947090)

To avoid having to click through to get it working, here's what you have to do:

```
pyspark --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=<jdbc.jar> --driver-class-path <jdbc.jar> --jars <jdbc.jar> --master <master-URL>
```

Comment: Uhm, the line of code is incomplete, right?  Which flags need a value after them?

Comment: yep, the markup was lost somehow -- I edited it back in

Comment: Much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea how to do this in PyCharm?