# Connecting from Spark/pyspark to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jar, apache-spark, pyspark

I've installed Spark on a Windows machine and want to use it via Spyder. After some troubleshooting the basics seems to work:

```
import os

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "D:\Analytics\Spark\spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6"

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark_config = SparkConf().setMaster("local[8]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_config) 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

textFile = sc.textFile("D:\\Analytics\\Spark\\spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6\\README.md")
textFile.count()
textFile.filter(lambda line: "Spark" in line).count()

sc.stop()
```

This runs as expected. I now want to connect to a Postgres9.3 database running on the same server. I have downloaded the JDBC driver from here [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) and have put it in the folder D:\Analytics\Spark\spark_jars. I've then created a new file D:\Analytics\Spark\spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6\conf\spark-defaults.conf containing this line:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath        'D:\\Analytics\\Spark\\spark_jars\\postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc41.jar'
```

I've ran the following code to test the connection

```
import os

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "D:\Analytics\Spark\spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6"

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark_config = SparkConf().setMaster("local[8]")
sc = SparkContext(conf=spark_config) 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = (sqlContext
    .load(source="jdbc",
          url="jdbc:postgresql://[hostname]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]",
          dbtable="pubs")
 )
sc.stop()
```

But am getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for     jdbc:postgresql://uklonana01/stonegate?user=analytics&password=pMOe8jyd
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:128)
at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.DefaultSource.createRelation(JDBCRelation.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:265)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I check whether I've downloaded the right .jar file or where else the error might come from?

Comment: I've tried postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc41.jar and quite a few other .jar files. I also tried adding `#s.environ["SPARK_CLASSPATH"]="D:\\Analytics\\Spark\\spark_jars\\*"` but this gives the error `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Found both spark.driver.extraClassPath and SPARK_CLASSPATH. Use only the former.` which implies that the above version should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spark-defaults.conf and add the SPARK_CLASSPATH to the system environment in python like this:

```
os.environ["SPARK_CLASSPATH"] = 'PATH\\TO\\postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar'
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried SPARK_CLASSPATH environment variable but it doesn't work with Spark 1.6.

Other answers from posts like below suggested adding pyspark command arguments and it works.

[Not able to connect to postgres using jdbc in pyspark shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669420/not-able-to-connect-to-postgres-using-jdbc-in-pyspark-shell)

[Apache Spark : JDBC connection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29821518/apache-spark-jdbc-connection-not-working)

```
pyspark --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=<jdbc.jar> --driver-class-path <jdbc.jar> --jars <jdbc.jar> --master <master-URL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to connect pyspark with your postrgresql db.

1) Install spark with pip: pip install pyspark

2) Download last version of jdbc postgresql connector in:
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

3) Complete this code with your db credentials:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def jdbc_dataset_example(spark):
    df = spark.read \
        .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://[your_db_host]:[your_db_port]/[your_db_name]",
              "com_dim_city",
              properties={"user": "[your_user]", "password": "[your_password]"})

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("[your_table]")

    sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM [your_table] LIMIT 10")
    sqlDF.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL data source example") \
        .getOrCreate()
    jdbc_dataset_example(spark)
    spark.stop()
```

Finally run your aplication with:

```
spark-submit --driver-class-path /path/to/your_jdbc_jar/postgresql-42.2.6.jar --jars postgresql-42.2.6.jar /path/to/your_jdbc_jar/test_pyspark_to_postgresql.py
```